# Chart Maximizing

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to the render the chart in bigger size as popup in another container. I tried changing the `innerHTML` using javascript but the chart is not functioning and I tried to redraw the chart after setting the `innerHTML`.

Intially chart will be rendered to "SmallContainer" on button click,

```
document.getElementById("LargeContainer").innerHTML = document.getElementById("SmallContainer").innerHTML 
document.getElementById("SmallContainer").innerHTML = "";
chartobj.redraw();
```

Here I am rendering the "LargeContainer" as I want to the display larger container as popup along with some other text.

Can any help me in fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In case when chart is rendered you cannot modify size by innerHTML, because paths in SVG are calculated. But you can use `setSize` function which allows to resizing chart.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setSize()

Obivuosly you can use also highslide to generate popup like in the example http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/GqhEX/

Comment: Thanks for your time.
But i cant go with Hightslide.

How to use the same chart options for different containers.

Comment: You can generate two charts with differens sizes

Comment: Sebastian can you provide me a sample for that.